# finding radiobutton based on text from xpath

Tags: html, css, xpath

I want to find out the XPath expression for accessing the radiobutton present in the label tag for the text "text being present".

I have tried the following:

```
"//[@id=\"radioButtonSymbol\" and //*[text()[contains(.,'text being searched')]]
```

Here is the structure of the HTML:

```
<div>
 <label id="radioButtonSymbol" for="1"></label>
 <span>
  <span>
   <span>
    <span class="textPresent">
    "text being searched"
    </span>
   </span>
  </span>
</span>
<label id="radioButtonSymbol" for="2"></label>
 <span>
  <span>
   <span>
    <span class="textPresent">
    "text not being searched"
    </span>
   </span>
  </span>
</span>
</div>
```

Can anyone correct the XPath expression?

Comment: what do you want the XPath to return, `<label id=radioButtonSymbol></label>` ?

Comment: Your HTML is not well-formed i.e attribute value should be wrapped in quotes, `div` element has no proper closing tag

Comment: i just corrected the same.. and yes, i do want to return the label id="radioButtonSymbol"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is one possible XPath expression :**

```
//div/span[
    .//span[
        @class='textPresent' and contains(., 'text being searched')
    ]
]
/preceding-sibling::label[1][@id='radioButtonSymbol']
```

**<kbd>[xpathtester demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/c2d0769a2cef4dff9fb0485f3358ffeb)</kbd>**

**Explanation :**

- **`//div/span[....]`** : find `div` element, anywhere in the HTML document, and navigate to the child element `span` that contains ....
- **`.//span[@class='textPresent' and contains(., 'text being searched')]`** : ... `span` element where `class` attribute value equals `'textPresent'` and contains `'text being searched'`
- **`/preceding-sibling::label[1][@id='radioButtonSymbol']`** : then from the outer `span` mentioned in the first bullet above, return the nearest preceding sibling `label` where `id` attribute value equals `'radioButtonSymbol'`

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the structure of your html is correct (but mind, the sample you posted is malformed as you miss '"' around the attributes)

Here is your xpath:

```
//label[@id="radioButtonSymbol"]/following::span[@class="textPresent"]/text()
```

which returns:

```
"text being searched"
```